# How to reffer to Planet Earth using just "Planet"?

Tags: grammar, articles, capitalization

Could you please advice should i add 'the' before planet when referring to our planet Earth? And should the words "the" and "planet" be capitalized?
So is the sentence written in the following way: "Work for The Planet." (meaning planet Earth) written correct?
Thanks,
Luk

Comment: I googled the commonly-heard expression 'saving the planet'. A few results used a capital 'P' but most did not. 'The' definitely does not need a capital letter (unless it is at the beginning of a sentence!) PS 'I' should always be capitalised, though!